# How to modify the name of the connection that Excel shows in the interface in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, connection

This is the first question I create in the forum although I have been reading it for a while and finding solutions. It should be pretty straighforward but there is something I am missing.

I am using VBA to create connections in excel to a couple of URLs. The attribute ".name" of the connection does not seem to be working properly. It does create the connection with the desired name but the name of the connection shown in the List of Connections is just the standard "Conection" ("Conexión" in Spanish).

By using the macro recorder I got that the same ".name" can be used to modify the name. But it is still not working.

This is just the part of the code I am having problems with right now.

GroupURL, QueryString and DestinationRange are variables.
An example of GroupURL is "Q35G10/".

```
With Worksheets(DestinationSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=QueryString, _ 
                                                   Destination:=Range(DestinationRange))    
        'This line just does not work but I do not know what it is for.
        .CommandType = 0    
        'The name has a problematic final character that is deleted this way (Ex: "/").
        .Name = "Dump_" & Left(GroupURL, Len(GroupURL) - 1)  
        
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

This gave results like the image of the following link (Sorry for the blue, is covered stuff)

[[image: Excel GUI Snapshot]

So I tried adding the following line at the end to modifiy the name again:

```
 Worksheets(DestinationSheet).Connections("Dump_" & Left(GroupURL, Len(GroupURL) - 1)).Name = "Prueba"
```

And it claims: "Error 438. The object does not allow this property or method."

Thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for [`QueryTable.Connection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.connection).

Comment: To try it, I have done the following:  the name of the connection ".Name = "Prueba"". And added the instruction: Worksheets(DestinationSheet).QueryTable.Connection("Prueba").Name = "PruebaFuera". Still error 438.

Comment: I am assuming there is no "language configuration issues in the Visiual Basic frame".

Comment: You need `.QueryTables(yourquerytablenameorindex)`.

Comment: I could not make it work like that. Instead, I used the macro recorder again to obtain a hint: 
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Conexión").Name
is what worked to change the Conection name. If I use it right after the connection is created, I am certain that I am modifiying the last created one. 
The problem is that relys on the language used for the system. I doubt it would work in other languages unless I create some sort of condition to check.

Comment: I have also tried to see how connections are ordered in the "Connections Collection" by doing dome tests with 
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1).Name
It turns out that they are order alphabetically, so
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count will not give you the pointer to the last created one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things:

- The `QueryTable` name, which is the name that is was creating.

  ```
    queryTables.Add(...) .name
  ```
- The connection name, which is the one Excel shows. Managed with

  ```
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).Name
  ```

By default, Excel arranges the connections alphabetically, and just adds the name "Connection" & CorreltiveNumber. As you can see in the image whenever a connection is created. This is language sensitive to your application setup.

[Connections Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrugC.jpg)

As I am creating several connections at once, I created a new sub to create them and rename each one, one by one, given that the name is going to be "Connection#". To do this, this is the solution I came up with, which checks if the connection name is already in use and works for Spanish and English.

```
Private Sub Create_Connection(ConnectionSheet As String, QueryString As String, DestinationRange As String, QueryName As String, ConnectionName As String)

Dim ConnectionCount As Long, i As Long, ConnectionMarker As Long, NamelessConnectionCount As Long

'Create connection
    With Worksheets(ConnectionSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=QueryString, Destination:=Range(DestinationRange))
    'If the connection already exists with the same name, excel adds ... "_#".

    'The Name of the Connection will be the value of the Origin Cell
    .Name = QueryName
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

'Check how many deffault name connection exist
ConnectionCount = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count
NamelessConnectionCount = 0
For i = 1 To ConnectionCount

If Left(ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).Name, 8) = "Conexión" Or _
    Left(ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).Name, 10) = "Connection" Then
        ConnectionMarker = i
        NamelessConnectionCount = NamelessConnectionCount + 1
End If
Next

'Change the name of the connection to a controlled one.
    If NamelessConnectionCount = 1 Then
        For i = 1 To ConnectionCount
            If ActiveWorkbook.Connections(i).Name = ConnectionName Then
                    MsgBox "The desired connection name " & ConnectionName & " is already in use." & vbCrLf & _
                    "Connection created with deffault name.", vbOKOnly, "Create Connection Error"
                    GoTo Label
            End If
        Next
        
        With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(ConnectionMarker)
            .Name = ConnectionName
            .Description = ""
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Error creating connection. The number of Nameless connections is not 1" & vbCrLf & _
                "Connection created with deffault name.", vbOKOnly, "Create Connection Error"
    End If

'Update connection
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections(ConnectionName).Refresh

Label:
End Sub
```